# Uso de WebView en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, webview-android

Estoy trabajando actualmente con WebView de Android Studio, y necesito orintación básicamente en los Siguientes aaaspectos:
1.- Como descargar archivos, pr ejemplo fotografías.
2.- Ver la url por las cuales está navegando.
Adjunto código de lo ya realizado

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.miapp.MESSAGE";
TextView tv1;
EditText ed1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);


    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    ClickShrinkEffectKt.applyClickShrink(fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            irSegundaActivity(view);
        }
    });
}
public void irSegundaActivity(View view){
    String send_string = ed1.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,send_string);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView wv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

   wv1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv1);
   String URL = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
   wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
   wv1.loadUrl("http://"+URL);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && wv1.canGoBack()) {
        wv1.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

El primer código es el ActivityMain, con el respectivo intent que dirige a la segunda clase MainActivity2, que finalmente contiene el WebView.La segunda actividad tiene un método onKeyDown, que permite retroceder a paginas navegadas anteriormente con el botón de ir atrás del teléfono.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Agrega lo que trataste por favor, saludos

Comment: La pregunta, tal y como está formulada, sugiere que estás buscando ejemplos. Voto por cerrarla.

Comment: @Jorgesys en el transcurso del día público lo que he elaborado. Ahorita no estoy en casa. Solo he hecho lo siguiente: desde el MainActivity envío un intent con una url a una segunda actividad que controla el layout que contiene el WebView. Esta segunda actividad captura el intent y hace desplegar la página según la url recibida. Hasta los momentos funciona, necesito mejorarla agregando funcionalidades como poder descargar archivos y ver las url por donde voy navegando.

Comment: @Jorgesys reformulada la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Para la pregunta Numero 1, puedes usar esto en kotlin:

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener { url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimetype, contentLength ->
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
            startActivity(intent)
        };
```

Y para la pregunta del numero 2, dentro del WebViewClient puedes ver muchos mas estados, yo solo he puesto dos pero hay muchos mas, dale un vistazo y usa el que mas te convenga:

puedes usar:

```
mWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            // Aqui podras ver la url cuando empieza a cargar
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            // Cuando la URL acaba de cargar
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias @David.Cruz, estoy trabajando con Java.

Comment: solo tienes que convertir el mismo codigo en java.

Comment: Así lo haré @David.Cruz

Comment: de nada  henriquezruben.